# Processing multidimensional csv-originated arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

Within the first column of every row lies a position, i.e. Software Engineer, and if the user's position matches the one in that row, the nested for loop should check in each column of that row if the given id exists in the csv string for that column. I haven't worked much with arrays in PHP and most of my experience with multidimensional arrays lies within Java so pardon my java-themed PHP code:

```
$csv = read_csv('/filepath/tct.csv');
$csv_rows = 75;
for($i=1;$i<$csv_rows;$i++)
{
    if(strtolower($user['user_pos']) == strtolower($csv[$i][0]))
    {
        for($j=1;j<sizeof($csv[$i]);j++)
        {
            if(array_search($user['id'], explode(",",$csv[$i][$j])))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my java doesn't seem to work and all of the existing questions concerning PHP multidimensional arrays only confuse me with the $key->$value talk. Can anyone explain to me what I need to do adjust to get this to work?

Comment: `$key` is the index of array and `$value` is the value of the given index.

Comment: I don't know if it's going to help you but PHP arrays begin to 0 like Java. All your `for` loops begin to 1. I think you should do `for($i=1;$i<=$csv_rows;$i++)` or `for($i=0;$i<$csv_rows;$i++)`

Comment: I had figured that I could start at 1 since no id values would ever be in the first column of a row (positions are there instead). At least, that was my thinking...I could be wrong.

Comment: If you have 10 records, in PHP, to go through all element it begins at 0 to 9. So you can do`$i=0 to $i<10` OR `$i=1 to $i<=10`. Take care of `<=` because it seems you're missing one element in each loop. I don't know if you understand what I mean. You can begin to 1 but you are missing one element because you `<10` gives you 9 (because integer)

Comment: I understand that. If I'm not mistaken, the first value in each row [0] *should* be a position (as per the format of the csv), which is something that, outside of my initial conditional, is irrelevant. I only want to check columns [1] and onward in that row.

Comment: Oh, and I started the row loop at [1] too because the first row contains only column names which have no bearing on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was doing is a perfectly acceptable (in terms of functionality) when processing multidimensional arrays, I just neglected to place the $ before j twice in the inner loop.

The most efficient and understandable way I've found thus far is:

```
foreach($csv as $csv_row) {
    for($i=1;$i<count($csv_row);$i++) {
        //do something with $csv_row[$i]
    }
}
```

The standard-issue nested for loop is to ensure the row names aren't iterated over since I always had row names at column[0] (despite the fact that the outer foreach will loop over the column names in row 0)

Of course, this is heavily reliant on someone using the same spreadsheet/csv layout. If it's a csv of just data, I'm sure the inner loop could be changed to:

```
foreach($csv_row as $csv_col {
    //do something with $csv_col
}
```